# Is it possible to recreate this effect with text rather than an image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

The top example specifically:

http://jsbin.com/ococal/3

To be precise, I'd like to use a `<p>` instead of a background image.

Comment: Yeah sure. But these kind of cosmic vacuum explosions within a transparent cube require a very large number of characters, each relatively positioned, in a certain colour, in ultra tiny fonts.

Comment: If the question asks what NGLN and I think.. Then, what you are going for doesnt make much sense to me.

Comment: Hehe, I'm pretty sure he wants to use a <p> with content instead of a background-image.. But I totally agree - Rumor has it cosmic vacuum explosions aren't gonna be supported until HTML6

Comment: @Lollero I was actually joking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible. Generally, you have to place your text inside `#reveal` and offset it by the same number of pixels that `#reveal` is moved, but negative.

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/ohociz/2/edit#preview).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a square white image with a transparent circle in the middle and just position it around, and then have different elements with white background mask the rest of the image.

```
<div>
  <img src="http://example.com/img.png"/>
  <div id="masking-circle"></div>
  <div id="mask-top"></div>
  <div id="mask-bottom"></div>
  <div id="mask-left"></div>
  <div id="mask-right"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

It's a game of z-index values
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp
and a mousemove listener